# Dot Net Web service not returning text

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, iis

Very basic issue. I am new to .net environment. I have used Visual studio to generate a web service. The web service simply takes in a text argument and creates a audio file from this text. Unfortunately the service does not return any text message back to webpage.

I am pasting the method.

Please suggest possible issues.

```
[WebMethod]
    public String AudioFileCreator(string inputText) {

        textReader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        textReader.Rate = -2;
        string myDirectory ="d:\\audio\\";
        FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream("file.wav", FileMode.Create,  FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        textReader.SetOutputToWaveStream(objfilestream);
        textReader.Speak(inputText);
        objfilestream.Close();
        textReader.Dispose();
        return "Done"; 
    }
```

I would also be great if some one could help me avoid the "d:\audio\" in the code. I am not aware of the default directory where the service could write the file to. Could any one guide me on this?

Comment: Does it throw any exception when you call it ?

Comment: I would suggest adding a try catch block to your code to see why the method is not returning the "Done" string, probably there is an exception happening

Comment: This code should throw a security exception if d:\\audio is not accessible by application's instance.

Comment: No it does not throw any exception. The audio file gets created as well... but the file cannot be played as the service still holds control on the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
public static string AudioFileCreator(string inputText)
```

Comment: It does not list as a web service then.